# Chinese Stack Exchange Computer

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the link to the Chinese Stack Exchange site that specialized in computer vocabulary. The site no longer opens with link I saved.  Thanks, Seee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is here:

[Chinese computer vocabulary, and most frequently encountered common computer terms](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/chinese-computer-vocabulary-and-most-frequently-encountered-common-computer-ter)

It lists a bunch of Chinese computer terminology. Should be what you're looking for.

When you can't find what you're looking for just use the search function (top-right). All I searched was "computer vocabulary", exactly what you wrote in the question, and the page came up straight away.